# Google Drive login recognized as Internet Explorer Login?

Tags: windows-8.1, google-drive

Could **Google Drive** login recognized as Internet Explorer Login ? I have just downloaded and installed Google Drive on Windows 8.1 and sign into, few moment later I get email from google ***New sign-in from Internet Explorer on Windows*** from Internet Explorer 7.0 (wich btw I dont have).

So, I am pretty sure that no one have my email password, and since this happens only few moments after I have installed google drive, does anyone know something about this strange behavior, or this is actually login from IE7

*I will change my passwords, sync, etc*

Comment: Did you download your google drive from google website or from an app store?

Comment: From web site. (https://www.google.com/drive/download/)

Comment: @malakrsnaslava, Is it your own personal consumer google account or is it your company Google Apps for Work account?

Comment: my personal google account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [an answer in Google Drive Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/C0-URgL-4Wk/xm8QlU81pRwJ), "*Google Drive uses IE to initially sign you in.  It is not used after that.*" So, that first login to the desktop client of Google Drive will be indeed recognized by Google as a "*New sign-in from Internet Explorer on Windows*" and therefore it is a legitimate login, so you can safely dismiss the warning email.

Just to be sure, go to ['Recent security events' on your Google Account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/notifications) and check the details of the reported Internet Explorer login, such as time, location and IP address. Most probably the data will match your current one, so you shouldn't worry. But if you are still in doubt, I'd apply the *"better safe than sorry"* policy and change the password and also turn on the [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en).

Comment: thanks, I have alredy checked that, but every computer at my company have same IP, so I narrow login to 50 people ;)

Comment: @malakrsnaslava Hi! I've just edited my answer and added further info about IE login from Google Drive desktop client that I've found in the Google Drive Support forums, I think you'll find it helpful... and reassuring.

Comment: I am convinced enough, but sitll a little bit confused why it is shown as IE7 when I have IE11, thanks Wayfarer